# How to use -Exclude to exclude all the contents of a specific folder in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Want to get all the contents of the `tree` folder, except for the L1 subfolder [^1].

which in the current case has two files, `fill.txt` and `dbg.log`.

Originally I wanted to use `-Exclude`, but after trying many usages I could not achieve.

```
# I don't know why the exclude parameter doesn't seem to work
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'tree' -Exclude 'tree\L1' | Should -Not -HaveCount 2
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'tree' -Exclude 'tree\L1\*' | Should -Not -HaveCount 2
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'tree' -Exclude "$('tree\L1'|Resolve-Path)*" | Should -Not -HaveCount 2
```

`Where-Object` works：

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'tree' | Where-Object {
    [string]$_ -notlike "$('tree\L1'|Resolve-Path)*"
} | Should -HaveCount 2
```

What's wrong with the way I use `Exclude` parameter? How to correct it?

supplement: That's just a case. I want to know how to use the `-Exclude` parameter to do this.

[^1]:

```
\tree
├──L1
│  ├──L2
│  │  ├──L3
│  │  │  ├──300.txt
│  │  │  └──xtf.log
│  │  ├──L3_1
│  │  │  ├──123.fp
│  │  │  └──dbg.log
│  │  ├──300.txt
│  │  └──xtf.log
│  ├──L2_1
│  │  ├──150.txt
│  │  └──15x.txt
│  ├──L2_2
│  │  ├──dbg_2.log
│  │  └──dbg.log
│  └──tl.txt
├──dbg.log
└──fill.txt
```

Comment: In your `tree` structure, everything is inside the `L1` folder, not just the two files you mentioned.. Does that mean you want to list only the subfolders of L1 and their children, but not files directly in L1?

Comment: @Theo No.What I want to do is in the second code segment.The results of those code runs are correct.

Comment: `-Exclude` and `-Include` work on the item's Name only, not the full path. You might try `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'tree' -Exclude 'L1'`, but that will also exclude items in subdirectories that happen to be named `L1`.. If that is a viable possibility, I'd stick with using the Where-Object clause.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem tree -Recurse -Exclude l1,tl.txt `  should give you the result you expect but as Theo mentioned if there is an item (subfolder / archive) named exactly `L1` or `tl.txt` exactly you would be excluding those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you wan something which is not achievable by using the `-Exclude` parameter.

This parameter operates only with item names. Unfortunately, this gotcha is not well documented by the official documentation.